# Can't run C file in Visual Studio

Tags: c, linux, windows

I have a C file that I can run in Linux (Ubuntu) terminal, but when I try to run the C file in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10, it can't run, it says can't open source file (`unistd.h`, `sys/wait.h`,...). Why Linux (Ubuntu) can run but Visual Studio can't? Thanks!

Comment: What `.h` file exactly? Is it a part of your source code, or not?

Comment: Is the missing header file literally called `header.h`? That's not a standard library header or one I'd expect in a 3rd party library. So it's probably part of your code base, meaning you'll need to copy along with your .c file (and any other .c and .h files that may be part of your project).

Comment: Yes, it's part of the source code, the Ubuntu is quite heavy (I'm using VirtualBox), so I try to run the C file in Windows. The header files are `unistd.h`, `sys/wait.h`,...

Comment: @sepp2k, No, there are a lot of header files that can't be opened, but I just called `header.h` for short.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: "This question doesn't show any research effort."

Comment: `sys/wait.h` is linux-specific. You can try building with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), which emulates such stuff on Windows, but if it doesn't work, your only hope is setting up a virtual machine and running Linux on it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [`sys/wait.h` is used on a lot more than just Linux](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_wait.h.html#tag_13_71).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Should've said "POSIX-specific".

Answer (score 1):

> when I try to run the C file with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10, it can't run, it says can't open source file (unistd.h, sys/wait.h,...). Why Linux (Ubuntu) can run but Visual Studio can't? Thanks!

Because the header files `<unistd.h>` (see e.g. [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) etc...) and `<sys/wait.h>` (see [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)) are specific to the [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard, and sadly Windows is not POSIX compliant. I heard of [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) which is rumored to be some compatibility layer.

Windows is rumored to have its own [Windows API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

The C standard has a small and rather poor API, e.g. `fopen`, `fprintf` & `malloc` (it does not know about directories or processes). Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or newer. You could code in C (using a [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler)) some micro-controller like [Arduino](https://arduino.cc) - they don't have any operating systems or files.

BTW, you don't *run* the file, you compile it, and on Linux you'll better [use](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to compile it and get warnings and debug info. Once your program has been debugged with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) (and perhaps even with the [address sanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html)), you could ask the GCC compiler to optimize it, by adding `-O3`.

A possible approach might be to use some framework library which has been ported to both Linux and Windows. You could try using [GTK](https://gtk.org/). It is gives you a common [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) (a documented set of types, declared functions and header files) which is implemented on Linux, Windows and MacOSX. With some care, a set of C files using GTK on Linux could be recompiled on Windows (with GTK available on it).

If you can afford learning C++ (see [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and read [*Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)) you could consider using C++ frameworks like [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/). Notice that learning C++ takes months of efforts.

My recommendation is to **study for inspiration the source code of *existing* open source software**, like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/), or [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), etc. You would learn a lot by contributing to one of them.

Comment: So I just include the GTK, and I can compile in Visual Studio, right?

Comment: @abcd No. This answer just says that if the program was written using GTK instead of whatever it's using now, it might've worked under MSVC out of the box.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading GNU GCC, and run it from the command line.

```
$ gcc -Wall file.c -o file

$ ./file
```

Comment: @abcd You can get GCC on Windows, yes, but the one I have doesn't have `sys/wait.h`. Cygwin should have it.

Comment: I don't get it, I install GCC on Linux and it can compile the C file, but why GCC on Windows can't compile? Aren't GCC on Linux and Windows the same.

Comment: No, **GCC on Linux and GCC on Windows are different**. On Linux, GCC would produce (indirectly) [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files. On Windows, it will give [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) files!